# subdownloader error: Unable to download subtitle

Tags: subtitle

(blablabla = a name of a movie)
The subdownloader gives me this error: `Unable to download subtitle blablabla.srt`.
If somebody knows please answer with simple english since i'm new to ubuntu and new to english. I am using ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.

I hope to find a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the workaround as I have been facing the same issue for many months now, and no new fixrelease has come since.

Follow the steps from Filip here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/subdownloader/+bug/790753/comments/19

in order to patch the GUI of our favorite tool.

Very simple:

```
leafpad /usr/share/subdownloader/gui/main.py
```

(with admin rights)

find the line :

```
osHttpRequests.download('http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/download/file/%s.gz' %sub.getIdFileOnline(), destinationPath)
```

and replace it with:

```
self.OSDBServer.DownloadSubtitles({sub.getIdFileOnline():destinationPath})
```

Save and Enjoy
Cheers.

Comment: you may change leafpad by the text editor of your choice: nano, gedit, vi ...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:

http://forum.opensubtitles.org/viewtopic.php?t=1303

> 100 downloads for 12 hours per IP, there is no limit I think, but out search result is limited to 250 results

Comment: Can you include what it states about `Unable to download subtitle XXXXXX.srt` in the link you provided by editing your answer?